# How to change btn text on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have built a basic btn. i need some help with creating the jquery.

the functionality i need is the following.

once clicked on the **"follow btn"**  the button turns **green** and says **following.**

once you hover back over the btn it needs to turn **red** and say **unfollow.**

If then pressed the button will then turn back to grey and say follow.

can anybody help with this?

Please update the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/a3LGN/

```
<a href="#"class="follow-btn"><span>Follow</span></a>

.follow-btn{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 1.6em "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: none !important;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    background:grey
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having with it? From your question it sounds like you just can't be arsed doing it yourself.

Comment: What you're asking for is relatively simple so I'm positive someone here will be able to help.  However, the Fiddle you've provided doesn't show any of what you've already tried.  Perhaps you could help us to help you by showing us what you've tried to-date and what it is you're actually getting stuck on, rather than just assigning us a task?

Comment: Thanks for you comment james, if i could write jquery i would do. im currenty learning

Comment: @user2965875 people learn by doing. Looking up each step and getting it to work. You don't learn from copying and pasting what someone else did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged `jquery` hoping you dont mind using `jquery` , then you can do something like this

```
$('#bt1').mouseenter(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1'))
{
$(this).css("background-color","red");
$('span').text("unfollow");
}
});
$('#bt1').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).addClass("follow-btn1");
$(this).css("background-color","green");
$('span').text("following");
});
$('#bt1').click(function(){
$(this).addClass("follow-btn1");
$(this).css("background-color","green");
$('span').text("following");
});
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3LGN/8/)

Comment: hi, thanks for you help. can you make all functions to click? and not hover?

Comment: But you asked that `unfollow` should appear on hover!

Comment: appolgises that is my mistake:(

Comment: So what exactly you want now ?

Comment: i have just read what i put and i do need it to hover and turn red, but i need to change back to grey if clicked. does that make sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41861/discussion-between-bharath-rallapalli-and-user2965875)

Answer (score 2):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3LGN/19/), is this what you want?

code:

```
var flag_clicked = false;

$('a.follow-btn').click(function() {
    if(flag_clicked) {
        $(this)
            .find('span')
            .text('Follow')
            .end()
            .css('backgroundColor','gray');
        flag_clicked = false;
    } else {
        $(this)
            .find('span')
            .text('following')
            .end()
            .css('backgroundColor','green');

        flag_clicked = true;
    }
}).hover(function() {
    if(flag_clicked) {
        $(this)
        .find('span')
        .text('unfollow')
        .end()
        .css('backgroundColor','red');
    }
},
    function(){
    if(flag_clicked) {
        $(this)
        .find('span')
        .text('following')
        .end()
        .css('backgroundColor','green');
    }         

         });
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. the only problem here is that when you have clicked to unfollow it goes back to follow (green). can you make it click to go back to unfollow. (grey)??

Comment: it all works apart from the last click. when clicking on unfollow it needs to go back to grey colour